# the draw outside bounding box in TikzEdt

Tags: tikz-pgf, wysiwyg

I have a problem with TikzEdt software. Everything works well with Miktex version of 2.9. However, when I upgrade Miktex to the version of 22, the TikzEdt does not work correctly. The following codes are automatically generated inside the preview.tex file.

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgftransformreset
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,line width=0pt,text width=0pt,text height=0pt] at (current bounding box) {};
%add border to avoid cropping by pdflibnet
\foreach \border in {0.1}
  \useasboundingbox (current bounding box.south west)+(-\border,-\border) rectangle (current bounding box.north east)+(\border,\border);
\newwrite\metadatafile
\immediate\openout\metadatafile=\jobname_BB.txt
\path
  let
    \p1=(current bounding box.south west),
    \p2=(current bounding box.north east)
  in
  node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,line width=0pt,text width=0pt,text height=0pt,draw=white] at (current bounding box) {
\immediate\write\metadatafile{\p1,\p2}
};
\immediate\closeout\metadatafile
```

I discover that the above codes make the draw out of bounding box of TikzEdt. It always generates a pdf of A4 size instead of the one fitting the draw.

here is the preamble in TikzEdt:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{circuitikz} %draw circuit
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%draw graph
\usepackage{pgfplots}%draw graph
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %draw 3d
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{float}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

and the codes generated inside preview.tex file

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw(-1,1) -- (4,0);
 
% \draw[draw=black] (7.5,3.5) rectangle ++(1,1);


\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgftransformreset
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,line width=0pt,text width=0pt,text height=0pt] at (current bounding box) {};
%add border to avoid cropping by pdflibnet
\foreach \border in {0.1}
  \useasboundingbox (current bounding box.south west)+(-\border,-\border) rectangle (current bounding box.north east)+(\border,\border);
\newwrite\metadatafile
\immediate\openout\metadatafile=\jobname_BB.txt
\path
  let
    \p1=(current bounding box.south west),
    \p2=(current bounding box.north east)
  in
  node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,line width=0pt,text width=0pt,text height=0pt,draw=white] at (current bounding box) {
\immediate\write\metadatafile{\p1,\p2}
};
\immediate\closeout\metadatafile
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
cture}

\end{document}
```

I look around for a solution but I have not found any.
You would please help me to solve it.
Thank you in advance!.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am probably missing something, but if you use `\documentclass{article}`, it will by default generate a A4-sized document. If you use `\documentclass{standalone}`, you will get a document that has the size of the contents, for example of the `tikzpicture` you place inside the document (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Thank you very much Jasper Habicht. I have tried with standalone but I get the same result (It still generates A4 size page). I think the preview package takes charge of cutting the pdf to fit the draw. I have tried the code without the first part of codes I posted, the pdf fits the draw perfectly.

Comment: When I combine the above preamble with the document code you provide and compile, I don't get an A4-sized document, no matter which document class I use. So, maybe the problem lies somewhere else. I only get a few (unrelated) errors and warnings: 1): `\documentclass[[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}` should really be just `\documentclass{standalone}`; 2) `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` leads to an option clash with `\usepackage{xcolor}`, removing the `pdftex` option solves this; 3) `\usepackage{filecontents}` is not needed since it is included in newer versions of LaTeX anyways.

Comment: Have you try to reinstall TikzEdt? If so you should remember, before to reinstall, to manually delete  the folder %user%/AppData/Roaming/TikzEdt that contain some settings.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, @vi pa: thank you very much for your support. I solved it already. First, I have installed all packages related to pgf and tikz in Miktex console, then I removed option of `pdftex` in `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` and removed temporary preview.tex file created before. Finally, everything is ok.